# How enable Skype spell checking?

Tags: skype, spell-checking

Is there a way to have spell checking enabled in Skype?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that skype for linux doesn't provide spell-checking at all. see this link: http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Spell-check-in-newest-Skype-for-Linux/td-p/1050184

Answer (score 2):

Skype does not provide spell checking, I'm not sure if you are able to enable it with a third party keyboard monitor or not. Hope this helps. 
I'm sorry if you required spell checking, but you could always type words your not sure how to spell in Google, to spell check them, then copy them into Skype chat.